# Create partition table in Entity Framework for Postgres?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "DKPositions",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                    ProviderEventId = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                    LastUpdated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_DKPositions", x => x.Id);
                });
```

I have been searching for some documents talking about partitioning tables in code-first Entity Framework design but I haven't been able to find anything. I am trying to partition this table by `LastUpdated`.

Is this possible with Entity Framework and a code-first design?

Comment: Related GH issue. It looks like it's not yet supported, but they are looking into it: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1035